# What is a good way to simulate O_NOFOLLOW on systems without this flag?

Tags: c, security, race-condition, symlink, posix-api

I would like to safely be able to simulate `open` with `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_NOFOLLOW` and `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_NOFOLLOW` on systems that do not support `O_NOFOLLOW`. I can somewhat achieve what I am asking for with:

```
struct stat lst;
if (lstat(filename, &lst) != -1 && S_ISLNK(lst.st_mode)) {
    errno = ELOOP;
    return -1;
}

mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_NOFOLLOW, mode);
```

but then I introduce a race condition and possibly a security problem.

I thought about maybe creating a dummy file with only the user being able to write, kind of like `touch`ing `filename`, doing the `lstat` check, and then using `chmod` after I finish writing (to correct the file mode bits), but I could be overlooking something major (e.g. if the file at `filename` exists, is not a regular file, or is already a symbolic link).

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposal still has a race condition:

- Mallory creates the link he wants you to follow;
- You `open()` the link with `O_CREAT`;
- Mallory replaces the link with a regular file;
- You do your `lstat()` test, which passes (not a link);
- Mallory replaces the regular file with the link again.

You can fix this for the non-`O_TRUNC` case by calling `fstat()` on your open file descriptor as well as `lstat()` on the path, and ensuring that the `.st_dev` and `.st_ino` members are the same.

However, this doesn't work if you're using `O_TRUNC` - by the time you've discovered the deception, it's too late - Mallory has already induced you to truncate one of your important files.

I believe the traditional way to eliminate the hole without `O_NOFOLLOW` support is:

- Create a temporary directory with mode `700`.  Error (or retry) if `mkdir()` fails due to existing directory;
- Create your new file within the temporary directory;
- Use `rename()` to atomically move the temporary file to the target name;
- Remove the temporary directory.