# Simulating O_NOFOLLOW (2): Is this other approach safe?

Tags: c, security, race-condition, symlink

As a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917395/), I thought of another approach which builds off of @caf's answer for the case where I want to *append* to file `name` and create it if it does not exist.

Here is what I came up with:

1. Create a temporary directory with mode 0700 in a system temporary directory on the same filesystem as file `name`.
2. <s>Open file `name` for reading only and `O_CREAT`. The OS may follow `name` if it is a symbolic link.</s>
   <s>Use `mkstemp` to create a temporary file in the temporary directory and attempt to `rename` the temporary file that was created by `mkstemp` to file `name`.</s>
   Open file `name` for reading only and `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.
3. Iteratively attempt to make a hard link to `name` at a temporary name within the temporary directory. If ever the [`link`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/link.html) call fails due to an error other than "the link target exists" (errno `EEXIST`), then exit. (Maybe someone has come along and removed the file at `name`, who knows?)
4. Use [`lstat`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/lstat.html) on `temp_name` (the hard link). If `S_ISLNK(lst.st_mode)`, then exit.
5. [`open`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/open.html) `temp_name` for writing & append (`O_WRONLY | O_APPEND`).
6. Write everything out. Close the file descriptor.
7. [`unlink`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/unlink.html) the hard link.
8. Remove the temporary directory.

(All of this, by the way, is for an [open source project](https://launchpad.net/wronly) that I am working on. You can view the source of my implementation of this approach [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dtrebbien/wronly/trunk/annotate/head:/src/wronly.c).)

Is this procedure safe against symbolic link attacks? For example, is it possible for a malicious process to ensure that the inode for `name` represents a regular file for the duration of the [`lstat`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/lstat.html) check, then make the inode a symbolic link with the `temp_name` hard link now pointing to the new, symbolic link?

I am assuming that a malicious process cannot affect `temp_name`.

**EDIT:** [`link`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/link.html) does not overwrite the target so creating a "placeholder" temporary file is not what I wanted to do. I have since updated my code and have updated the steps above.

**EDIT2:** I am now using an alternate procedure for step 2 to create file `name` if it does not exist which I do not think is susceptible to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938563/2943452#2943452).

**EDIT3:** Even better than renaming a temporary, empty, regular file to `name`, which also has the effect of unlinking `name`, *then* renaming, I can open the file `O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.

The POSIX standard for `open` states:

> If `O_EXCL` and `O_CREAT` are set, and `path` names a symbolic link, `open()` shall fail and set `errno` to `EEXIST`, regardless of the contents of the symbolic link.

Comment: Your final POSIX citation looks like an answer. If so, why not post it as an answer and accept it, so this question no longer shows up as "unanswered"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is one problem with step 2 ("Open file `name` for reading only and `O_CREAT`. The OS may follow `name` if it is a symbolic link.") which, if fully exploitable, could allow an unprivileged process to essentially `touch` any path in the filesystem. The consequences of this include forcing a disk check on the next reboot (by touching `/forcefsck`), as well as other, more destructive things. For example, in upgrading from Debian Lenny to Squeeze, both dbus and the kernel image have to be upgraded at the same time because each of the corresponding packages depends on the other (the new dbus doesn't work with the old kernel and the old dbus doesn't work with the new kernel). The way that the admin gets around this circular dependency is by `touch`ing a specific path, which informs the new dbus package that the kernel image is going to be upgraded before the next reboot. If, however, a malicious process manages to `touch` that path before a first upgrade & reboot during the upgrade from Lenny to Squeeze, then the system may not be bootable. The first upgrade, if I recall correctly, installs the new dbus, but you have to explicitly upgrade again for the new kernel image to install. *One* upgrade followed by a reboot might brick the system.

Looking through the [source of GNU Coreutils' `touch`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c), it appears that they only set the file timestamps, but do not create the file if it does not exist, when `touch` is passed the `--no-dereference` option. They do this with a utility function, [`lutimens`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/utimens.c) from gnulib, which wraps Linux's [`utimensat`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/utimensat.2.html), allowing the timestamps of the symbolic link file itself, if that is the case, to be updated when Linux >= 2.6.22.